# Jenkins : withCredentials does not mask passwords in Groovy Script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, credentials, jenkins-groovy

I am using Credentials and CredentialBinding to mask credentials passed to "bat" to be used in "net use" to connect to a share via a groovy script. Unfortunately the password is exposed in console log :

```
    withCredentials([
        usernamePassword(
            credentialsId: credentialsId,
            passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD',
            usernameVariable: 'USER'
        )
    ]) {
        def user = this.env['USER'];
        def password = this.env['PASSWORD'];        
        bat "net use \\\\$server $PASSWORD /user:$user /persistent:yes"
        bat "net use"
    }
```

I tried using %PASSWORD% in single quotes as well , but strings are not getting interpolated in "net use".
Please let me know if something is amiss.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your log that you get (obviously with the password removed)
As `withCredentials` should mask automatically if you have a reasonably recent version even when passing to other processes
e.g.

```
    steps {
            withCredentials([
                usernamePassword(
                    credentialsId: "MY_CREDENTIALS",
                    passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD',
                    usernameVariable: 'USER'
                )
            ]) {
                sh "echo $PASSWORD"
                echo USER
            }
        }
```

will still mask the password

```
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of $USER or $PASSWORD
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
Warning: A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
     Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [PASSWORD]
     See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.
+ echo ****
****
[Pipeline] echo
****
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
```

Also what are these lines for when you can just use $PASSWORD and $USER directly

```
def user = this.env['USER'];
def password = this.env['PASSWORD'];
```

Comment: Pasting logs below (Have hashed out passord and changed some details) 
  `Masking supported pattern matches of %USER% or %PASSWORD%
  [Pipeline] {
 [Pipeline] bat
 Warning: A secret was passed to "bat" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
    Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [PASSWORD, USER]
   See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.
 
    net use \\source.com #### /user:**** /persistent:yes 
 The command completed successfully.`

Comment: Do you have any special characters in user / password combination? If you switch to `sh` instead of `bat` then above is the answer (without special characters). If you really need to use `bat` can you try it like this:
`bat 'net use ' + "\\\\${server} " + '%PASSWORD% /user:%user% /persistent:yes'`

Maybe you will need to adjust the path though, but in this case the credentials should be masked.

Comment: Yes we do use special characters , since the environment is windows, I have never tried sh there.

Comment: What I noticed is using % and ' in bat doesnt pass correct values to "net use"

Comment: What kind of special characters do you use? In the past we did had combination of `%`, `#` and `&` in a password and we got rid of those as it also gave some problems. If you try the command locally, can you bind the network drive to a local drive successfully (or do you need to escape the special characters)?

Comment: We are indeed using % and to pass them using groovy , we have to escape them.